# How to present results of restricted cubic splines in a cox regression

Tags: r

I have used the 'rms' package to use restricted cubic splines in my cox regression model.

Example of my univariate code

```
S_HTN<-Surv(data_HTN$time+data_HTN$age, data_HTN$event_HTN)
htn_dd<-datadist(data_HTN)
option(datadist='htn_dd')
HTN_spline<-cph(S_HTN~rcs(centiles,3), data=data_HTN)
```

I have plotted these via ggplot fine but what I want to know if I can see where the knots are and then use these in other analyses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the formula of your fitted model along with the knot locations by using the function `Function()`, i.e. `Function(HTN_spline)`.

However, you can also adjust knot locations manually, with `x`, `y` and `z` being your three desired knots:

```
HTN_spline <- cph(S_HTN ~ rms::rcs(centiles, c(x, y, z)), data=data_HTN)
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! I have a couple of models with different outcomes and when I use Function() the knots (if they have the same number of knots) all occur at the same place. I assume this is to be expected? (unless I predefine them)

Comment: @AnnieWright I fear I‘m not good enough a statician to answer taht. But over at crossvalidated there‘s a bunch of clever people who certainly can answer that. Sorry!